# PHP and an int with a value of 200 being treated as 2 100%, to declare another variable

Tags: php, int

I have quite an original problem and am unsure how I can achieve it in the best way.

I have a variable let us say that it is called `percent`, it is an int that can hold any value between 0 - 200.

While the number of `percent` is not more than 100, it is treated as a percent to work out another variable, let us say that for each 1% you get 2 apples.

```
$percent = 89;
$apples = $percent*2;
```

While the number of percent is more than 100 upto the value of 200, it should work in reverse. So if `percent` equaled to 101 it should act as 99%.

Basically how can I easily calculate the amount of apples from `percent` which is an int ranging from 0-200, when I need the number to act like below...

**If `percent` equals 0-99**

Acts as a normal percentage value

**If `percent` equals 100**

The max value for apples

**If `percent` equals 101-200**

For each increment over 100, it should take from the max value of apples.

I think I explained it good enough,

Thanks.

Comment: You've got the logic worked out, mate.  Just use if else's.

Comment: Ye thought about it, just didn't know if php had a built in function for it there are so many, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the elegant mathematical approach is the following:

```
$true_percent = 100 - abs(100 - $percent);
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this, not sure what is going on but I will research it.

Answer (score 3):

Try `100 - abs(100 - $percent)`.

`abs(100 - $percent)` gives you the distance between the two values. It is `1` for both `99` and `101`.

Subtracting this distance from `100` gives you the desired ouput.

Comment: This would work as if `percent` equalled 99, it should be 99% but if `percent` equalled 101 it should be 99% also and not 1. Unless I am missing something, thanks for reply

Comment: This is the exact same formula as in the answer you accepted. Why would the output be different?